# IBM Websphere JSP dispatcher rendering as a redirect

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

Is there a way to **configure websphere** not to **redirect** to the JSP page when simply I want to render the JSP from my spring mvc controller?

For instance, **request.getCurrentURL()** from within the view ( JSP ) page, returns the url for the JSP page, instead of the controller and action that was hit to render it.

This is causing problems with sitemesh for instance when trying to match the url to be decorated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    ... 
    <property name="alwaysInclude" value="true"/>        
</bean>
```

Add always include to the properties of your internal view resolver